# Insert data into SQL Server from form using Power app

Tags: sql-server, powerapps

I am trying to insert data/record into a SQL Server database using a powerapp application.

I have created form and submit the form using button it's showing this error:

[image]

Another way I am trying with Patch code in onselect:

```
Patch(datasource,default(datasource),{columnname: 12})
```

Can you please help out to fix or insert the data into table?

Comment: How are you defining the form interactions (are you calling `NewForm(FormName)` and then calling `SubmitForm(FormName)` on the button)? What is the definition of the table, does it contain any required columns that are not being provided?

Comment: In button on select option i am writing as: SubmitForm(FormName). Database i have columns : PK_ID,FK_ID 's of all Dim table and the value.

Comment: Do you have all required columns in the form (or in the Patch call)?